# Save Gmail messages to flash drive

Tags: gmail, export

I need to move Gmail conversations to hard/flash/dvd drive for an investment scam (no, it's not Ugandan) investigation and prosecution...  How to do this?

Comment: Download the emails on the account within any desktop email client that works on your operating system.  You ould also easily simply print the email into a pdf file if you wanted.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with just saving the files?

Comment: The Data Liberation Front has a short [help page on how to get your email out of Gmail](http://www.dataliberation.org/google/gmail).

Answer (score 1):

Scott Hanselman wrote an article about this. There is a tool which helps make backup of your Gmail emails. Although he is talking about automatic task, you can get the idea from his article [Automatically Backup your Gmail account on a schedule with GMVault and Windows Task Scheduler](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AutomaticallyBackupYourGmailAccountOnAScheduleWithGMVaultAndWindowsTaskScheduler.aspx)

The tool is called GMVault and you can download it at http://gmvault.org/. It's pretty straightforward to use it.

Comment: Answers should be self-contained. When that link no longer functions there is no useful information here.

Answer (score 0):

See also [this related question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/417/export-gmail-messages-to-text-or-html-files?rq=1) recommending [IMAPSize](http://www.broobles.com/imapsize/imap-backup.php). There is also [GMAIL Backup](http://www.gmail-backup.com/documentation). Both are only for Windows.

[OfflineIMAPP](https://github.com/nicolas33/offlineimap#readme) however runs on Linux and MacOS and stores your emails offline in the Maildir format.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout **Beyond Inbox**, which helps make backup of your Gmail emails to hard drive or any other account too. It runs on all the OS including Windows, Linux and Mac.

Download Beyond Inbox from here : http://www.beyondinbox.com/beyondinbox-download.html

Comment: Please state if you affiliated with this company. I would suggest you take some to read the [FAQ], in particular the section [regarding promotion](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion)